# Can I use Android ExoPlayer to rewind an HLS stream that is a live event?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I have an .m3u8 file that has no #EXT-X-ENDLIST tag. ExoPlayer plays the stream just fine.

What I would like to do is have the following functionality:

1. Press the rewind button to go back X seconds.
2. Press the forward button to resume the live stream.

Is such a thing possible with ExoPlayer?

Edit: actually, it seems that #2 may already work as I had hoped.

Comment: Seems like I can seekTo positions prior to the current position. But it may be that (out of the box) ExoPlayer doesn't keep a history of segments, i.e., the most I can rewind is to the beginning of the current segment. Still testing this theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this isn't possible (yet).

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/87